# Not able to get data in props in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Following is my code to retrieve data from firebase and view it in a bootstrap carousel. I can see the values in the console but I'm not able to get it in the props on another component.

```
class JobOfferSlider extends Component {
    componentDidMount = () => {
        var ref = fire.database().ref("Employers/Employer1");
         ref.orderByKey().on("child_added", (snapshot) => {
            this.setState({ slidercontents: snapshot.val()})
            console.log(this.state.slidercontents);
            console.log(this.state.slidercontents.Title)
        });
        var empref = fire.database().ref("Employers/");
        empref.orderByKey().on("child_added", (snapshot) => {
            this.setState({ employers: snapshot.key})
           console.log(this.state.employers);
       });

    }
    state ={
        slidercontents : [], employers : []
    }
```

and i use the props in the following jsx file

```
class Slidercontent extends Component {
    componentWillUpdate = ()=>{
        console.log(this.props.employers);
    }
    render() {
       return (
            <div className="col-sm text-center border rounded shadow p-3 m-3">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-3">
                        <div className="profilepic"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-9">
                        <h6 className="pt-2 float-left">{this.props.employers}</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <h5 className="font-weight-bold pt-3 text-left">{this.props.slidercontents.Description}</h5> 
                <h5 className="font-weight-bold pt-3 text-left ">{this.props.slidercontents.RatePerHour}</h5>
                <div className="row pt-3">
                    <div className="col-md-2">
                        <div><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i></div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-5">
                        <p className="float-left">{this.props.slidercontents}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-5">
                        <p className="float-right">5 mins ago</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

But the props stays undefined.... any help on how to access the state values?

Comment: Where do you pass the state to Slidercontent as props ?

Comment: how should i pass that? :)

Comment: In the parent component: render() { return <Slidercontent employers={this.state.employers} }

Answer (score 0):

Pass the parent component's state as props to the child component (in the render function):

```
render() { 
  return <Slidercontent employers={this.state.employers} 
}
```

This way, you can access the `employers` in the child component by:

```
{this.props.employers}
```